# how to create a function to generating a button using JQuery

Tags: javascript

This is the way I did , but I got "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

```js
function get_tag_elem() {
  let class_name = add_tag();
  let tag_elem = $('#meta_tag_element > button.bx--tag.bx--tag--color');
  tag_elem.removeClass('bx--tag--color');
  tag_elem.addClass(class_name);
  let tag_html = tag_elem.html()
  return $(tag_html);
}
```

```html
<button id="tag_value" class="bx--tag">
  <span class="bx--tag__label">Article Tag</span>
  <svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="will-change: transform;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" aria-hidden="true">
    <path d="M12 4.7L11.3 4 8 7.3 4.7 4 4 4.7 7.3 8 4 11.3 4.7 12 8 8.7 11.3 12 12 11.3 8.7 8z"></path>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant missing script in a [mcve]

Comment: I would try returning **tag_elem** instead, that way you aren't creating a new jquery element in the return which consists of the jquery's HTML content of the other variable

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to duplicate the button using an HTML template.

```js
var template = document.getElementById("tag_value").outerHTML;
var container = document.getElementById("container")
var id = 0;

function add_button() {
  $(container).append($(template.replace("tag_value", "btn" + ++id)))

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span style="display:none">
<button id="tag_value" class="bx--tag">
    <span class="bx--tag__label">Article Tag</span>
<svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="will-change: transform;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M12 4.7L11.3 4 8 7.3 4.7 4 4 4.7 7.3 8 4 11.3 4.7 12 8 8.7 11.3 12 12 11.3 8.7 8z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
</span>
<button onclick="add_button()">add button</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```